# Avoiding column prefix when loading multiple R files using lapply

Tags: r, list

I have a series of R files (each individually stored as data tables) that I can load one of two ways.

METHOD 1:

```
load ("WIOT2000_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2000 = wiot
load ("WIOT2001_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2001 = wiot
load ("WIOT2002_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2002 = wiot
load ("WIOT2003_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2003 = wiot
load ("WIOT2004_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2004 = wiot
load ("WIOT2005_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2005 = wiot
load ("WIOT2006_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2006 = wiot
load ("WIOT2007_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2007 = wiot
load ("WIOT2008_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2008 = wiot
load ("WIOT2009_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2009 = wiot
load ("WIOT2010_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2010 = wiot
load ("WIOT2011_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2011 = wiot
load ("WIOT2012_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2012 = wiot
load ("WIOT2013_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2013 = wiot
load ("WIOT2014_October16_ROW.Rdata")
wiot2014 = wiot

wiod = list(wiot2000,wiot2001,wiot2002,wiot2003,wiot2004,wiot2005,wiot2006,wiot2007,wiot2008,wiot2009,wiot2010,wiot2011,wiot2012,wiot2013,wiot2014)
```

METHOD 2:

```
 filenames = lapply(seq(2000,2014), function(x) paste("WIOT", x, "_October16_ROW.Rdata", sep="")

 wiod = lapply(filenames, function(x) as.data.table(mget(load(x))))
```

Both methods achieve the same result, but clearly method 2 is preferable. However, with method 2 the column names within each data frame are now preceded by "wiot" -- the pre-set name of each of the data tables.

Any ideas on how to avoid the "wiot" prefix with method 2?

Comment: You have included `paste("WIOT` in your function call. Remove that to not have it in the filename.

Comment: That's necessary because all of the R files start with "WIOT" (e.g., "WIOT2001_October16_ROW.Rdata"). The syntax above works perfectly fine -- the issue is that the column names within each data object read like "wiot.col1", "wiot.col2", etc.

Comment: If you check individual items, do you see those prefixes? (e.g. `colnames(wiod[[1]])`

Comment: Yes  I still see them

Comment: How about if you load one file, save the column names, then use them to rename the result.